# Crash in for loop (Android NDK)

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, crashlytics-android

I have the following code ( from a class member function of mine):

```
        this->mLengOfPath = mFirst->mLengOfPath + mSecond->mLengOfPath;
        unsigned short* data = mMiddle->mPathContainer;

        mMiddle->mLengOfPath = 0;
        for (int index = 0; index < mMiddle->mSize; index++) {   //crash here
            if (index % 2 == 1 && index > 2){
                mMiddle->mLengOfPath += 
                     GestureUtils::distance(data[index - 3], data[index - 2],
                     data[index - 1], data[index]);
            }
        }
```

In most case, this code doesn't crash. But crashlytics told me that my code "sometimes" crash at line 4, which I don't understand why. If mMiddle is nullptr, it should have crashed at line 2 (I already use mMiddle there).

But crashlytics consistently reports that line 4 is the problem. Anyone know how can my code go wrong at line 4?

Comment: Is `mMiddle` always a valid pointer?

Comment: If it is not valid, my code should crash at line 2, not line 4. That's what I don't understand.

Comment: @S.M. it might be not nullptr but still invalid. and effect of invlid pointer is unpredictable.  but in general that kind of for() might be unsafe if mSize may change by outside means.

Comment: That's the problem with [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (and dereferencing an invalid pointer, null or otherwise, is UB), all speculation about behavior becomes useless. Sometimes it might *seem* to work fine, and in the next moment it will crash and burn.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that mMiddle->mSize won't change while the for() is running. Its size is pre-calculated before this code runs.

Comment: @duy_sau_rom ah..so you work with one thread or lock it out. It's good to mention.  mMiddle doesn't change either?

Comment: I do work with multiple threads, but I locked it to make sure that only 1 thread can init at a time. Also, my init process does a lot of things and this is my only crash in it. If this is the problem with multithread, I guess many other crashes should have appeared. (my code would fail at different places too)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's UB, if pointer is invalid. But we have particular platform and compiler in mind, while talking Android NDK and a statistical tool. With native ARM code lines 1,2,4 lines may crash *sometimes* on invalid pointer, only writing to null pointer is 100% failure.

Line 3 will always fail if `mMiddle` is null, but may or may not if it points into data segment or not.  Statistical tool would highlight line 4 as it is one more often executed one: comparing expression is evaluated on every iteration. Failures on other lines may become statistical noise.